# Swagger/OpenAPI Bearer auth with custom header name

Tags: authentication, swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I'm defining (small parts of) an existing API ([Samanage](https://www.samanage.com/docs/api)) using OpenAPI to assist with some integration work.

I need to authenticate using Bearer auth, but by sending the token in a header other than `Authorize`.

The server expects Bearer authentication in a header named `X-Samanage-Authorization` like this example:

```
curl -H "X-Samanage-Authorization: Bearer <TokenGoesHere>" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.samanage.v2.1+json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json
```

I'm aware of https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/, but it doesn't seem to help me fully.

This (OpenAPI 3)

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
...
security:
- bearerAuth: []
```

Results in an authentication header named the default (`Authorization`)

```
curl -X GET "https://api.samanage.com/incidents/12341234.json" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <TokenGoesHere>"
```

Which then fails (401).

I feel like I want this:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      name: X-Samanage-Authorization
      in: header
      scheme: bearer
```

But that fails validation in Swagger Editor as I believe a `type` of `http` doesn't allow the `name` component (like a type of `apiKey` would). I couldn't quite make full sense of the docs [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#security-scheme-object) to be honest.

I did read about [Specification Extensions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#specificationExtensions) but being completely new to OpenAPI, I couldn't find any examples on how to actually implement what I need.

Any insight much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`type: http` is for HTTP authentication as defined by [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) and the [IANA HTTP Authentication Scheme Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). HTTP authentication, by definition, uses the `Authorization` header.

To use a custom header name, you need to define it as an [API key](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/) (`type: apiKey`):

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: apiKey
      name: X-Samanage-Authorization
      in: header
```

Note that since it's a non-standard Bearer scheme, the clients will need to manually add the "Bearer " prefix to the token value. For example, when you click "Authorize" in Swagger UI, you'll need to enter "Bearer TOKEN" instead of just "TOKEN".

Comment: Thanks Helen. I spotted this option already but still can't figure out how I get OpenAPI to specify the required 'Bearer' prefix - or is that not possible?

Comment: Is it possible to add username/password based authentication form in swager and get the custom auth token from response headers and use that token in this apiKey type with custom name. Its like oAuth Password grant but getting the custom token value from response header and instead of Bearer Token, its just X-API-Token: "custom token value " in header of ALL Api calls

Comment: @Mubasher: Did you find a way to do this? "getting the custom token value from response header" and feeding it into the custom header of all API calls. I am also having the same requirement.